# How to connect to FTPS using Ruby 2.3?

Tags: ruby, ftp, ruby-2.3

From what I see latest Ruby that supported FTPS was 1.8. I found some gems that can connect to FTPS, but they were no updated in several years. Did anyone had to do this recently? What gem did you use?

Comment: _For future references:_ As off **ruby-2.4.0** `Net::FTP` supports FTPS connections natively. Both FTP over SSL and FTP over TLS are supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`net/ftp`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html) standard library.

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new('cdimage.debian.org')
ftp.login
ftp.list
```

Or login to protected ftp:

```
ftp.login('username', 'password')
```

Answer (score -1):

And for FTPS you can use net/sftp https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp

example of code :

```
require 'net/sftp'

Net::SFTP.start('host', 'username', :password => 'password') do |sftp|
  # upload a file or directory to the remote host
  sftp.upload!("/path/to/local", "/path/to/remote")

  # download a file or directory from the remote host
  sftp.download!("/path/to/remote", "/path/to/local")

  # grab data off the remote host directly to a buffer
  data = sftp.download!("/path/to/remote")

  # open and write to a pseudo-IO for a remote file
  sftp.file.open("/path/to/remote", "w") do |f|
    f.puts "Hello, world!\n"
  end

  # open and read from a pseudo-IO for a remote file
  sftp.file.open("/path/to/remote", "r") do |f|
    puts f.gets
  end

  # create a directory
  sftp.mkdir! "/path/to/directory"

  # list the entries in a directory
  sftp.dir.foreach("/path/to/directory") do |entry|
    puts entry.longname
  end
end
```

Comment: SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) is not the same as FTPS (FTP over SSL). `Net::SFTP` will not help with connecting to an *ftps* server.